# DV360 traffic is not reported after enabling auto-tagging

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, dv360

We have a GA4 account for a website where DV360 account is linked. While using manual tagging everything was reported smoothly.

After enabling auto-tagging in DV360 panel the traffic from DV360 disappeared.We also have a considerable increase in "safeframe.googlesyndication.com / referral" traffic, which I suspect is what DV360 traffic should be.

DV360 has a pretty straightforward auto-tagging configuration, everything seems OK in the panel.
I have considered putting "safeframe" in referral exclusion list, but I suspect its only going to make things worse. It can result in increased "(not set)" traffic.
I can switch back to manual tagging, but its more prone to human error.

What do you suggest?